# Set manual Entity framework connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, database-connection, connection-string

I have a model that is created by `EF6` ,by default my connection string is initialized in `app.config` as you can see here :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShirazRailwayEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RailWay.csdl|res://*/RailWay.ssdl|res://*/RailWay.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=DB-Metro;user id=sa;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have 3 layers in my application `Model` ,`UI` ,`Domain class` .my connection string is initialized in 'Model' and 'UI' layers,I need to set `connection string` by user , i mean the connection string should be set by user.

My question :

As i said i have 2 layers that the connection string are initialized inside them ,Is it necessary to initialized both connection by user ? Or just the `UI` is enough ?Which connection string should be initialized ?

The next question is how can i set the connection string by user?

I have a repository layer between my `EF model` and `UI` called repository :

```
   public class StationRepository : GenericRepository<ShirazRailWay.ShirazRailwayEntities, DomainClass.Station>
    {
    }
```

My Ui calls this repository .

best regards

Answer (score 3):

> how can i set the connection string by user?

The `DbContext` class that underlies your Entity Framework context class has a constructor that takes in a `connectionString` parameter. If you expose that in your context, you can pass whatever connection string you want to it at runtime.

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext(GetCurrentUserConnectionString())
{
   ...
}
```

As for your other questions, I didn't really understand what you're asking. If you want a better answer, please clarify.

Comment: My model and Ui are in separate project i should initialize the ui connection string too ?

Comment: I don't call my dbcontext directly i have an repository between my model and ui how can i pass the connection string to my model.i mean i call my dbcontext in repository but my connection string should be initialized in ui

Comment: @EA - And why is that a problem?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch you know in my ui i have an app.config that my connection string is there ,in my repository layer i call my dbcontext ,i don't know how can i set connection string in ui by user and out it in dbcontext layer

Comment: @EA - The same way you do in your ui... I don't understand what problem you're having... it works exactly the same way.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch coult you please take a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741575/passed-dbcontext-connection-string-to-dalayer

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your dbcontext with custom connection string:

```
var context = new DbContext(connectionString);
```

**update:**

In your repository you can add parameter to constructor of repository that will initialize connection string for dbcontext.

Example:

```
public class StationRepository : GenericRepository<ShirazRailWay.ShirazRailwayEntities, DomainClass.Station>
{
    public StationRepository(string connectionstring):base(connectionstring){}
}

public class GenericRepository<T1, T2>
{
    protected GenericRepository(string connectionstring)
    {
        //initialize dbcontext using connection string
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but my problem is i have 3 layers in my app ,one of them is My model that my entities are there and ui and domain class ,if i set the connection string in model i should initialize it in ui too

Comment: Does every user has his own connection string? And how do you authenticate this user in your program?

Comment: I just need the user be able to choose ip address of server

Comment: In your repository you can add parameter to constructor of repository that will initialize connection string for dbcontext.

Comment: @it is that i want ,so could you please tell m in details?

Comment: For details i should look at your realization of GenericRepository.

Comment: Here you can see that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741575/passed-dbcontext-connection-string-to-dalayer?lq=1