# My dbcontext doesn't expect any connection string as an input

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-connection, dbcontext, data-layer

I have 4 layer in my application `UI`,`DomainClass`,`Model(DBCntext)`,`Repository`.

In repository i have an abstract class like this :

```
 public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> :
    IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
    {

        private C _entities = new C();
        public C Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

All my entities inheritance from this class like this :

```
namespace Repository
{
    public class StationRepository : GenericRepository<ShirazRailWay.ShirazRailwayEntities, DomainClass.Station>
    {
    }
}
```

I `UI` i called this repositories. as you can see here :

```
  stationrepository objnew=new stationrepository();
  obnew.getall();
```

In UI layer i have an connection string in `app.config` as you can see here :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShirazRailwayEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RailWay.csdl|res://*/RailWay.ssdl|res://*/RailWay.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=DB-Metro;user id=sa;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But i want to give an option to my users that with this option they can set their `connection string` by themselves.So i created a form in UI layer that when the users trying to `log in` it asks them the connection string .My problem is `How can pass this connection string to my dbcontext`?

In my `model layer(dbcontext)` i have this :

```
 public partial class ShirazRailwayEntities : DbContext
    {

        public ShirazRailwayEntities(string connectionName)
            : base(connectionName)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Line> Lines { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Path> Paths { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Station> Stations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Train> Trains { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TimeTable> TimeTables { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ConfigFont> ConfigFonts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ArrivalTime> ArrivalTimes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ConfigColor> ConfigColors { get; set; }
    }
```

i clear the connection string in `app.config` file ,but the application doesn't expect any connection string ,and it can't connect to database .why ?Where should i inject my connection string to dbcontext ?as you can see my constructor expects  an input.I need to do this in UI layer

best regards

Comment: As an aside to your actual question, I'd be asking myself what I am achieving by wrapping my DbSets in an extra repository layer.

Comment: My dbset is in model layer not repository

Comment: Well sure, but your repository layer still is merely wrapping simple operations already provided by the dbsets or the dbcontext itself. Unless there's more to it, IMHO, it seems like a repository layer for the sake of a repository layer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name of the connection string, not the connection string itself, like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ShirazRailwayEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RailWay.csdl|res://*/RailWay.ssdl|res://*/RailWay.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=****;initial catalog=DB-Metro;user id=sa;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

```
var context = new ShirazRailwayEntities("ShirazRailwayEntities");
```

or

```
var context = new ShirazRailwayEntities("someOtherConnectionStringInAppConfig");
```

Comment: How can i pass this to DAlayer from the ui ,it is the main question ?

Comment: Submit the form you mentioned then pass connection string name from POST'ed form data to the constructor for your ShirazRailwayEntities constructor as in the above.

Comment: I'd add more detail, but I'm not sure if you're using ASP.NET MVC, AngularJS, etc. In general though, it's as simple as having your user select the connection string name from a drop down of all connection string names, POSTing it to your server and passing it along to your DbContext constructor. Depending upon your needs, you may need to persist the selection in session, cookies, etc.